# What is the most elegant way to create an integer sequence in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with various columns, one of them being `priority` that is `INT`. The `priority` field is always a sequence from `1...n` indicating the priority/order of the data. Assume this to be always correct.

Now, in my app I have a function that will delete a row in this table. I would hence need to find an elegant way to redo the priority column after an entry has been removed. What is the most elegant way of doing that directly in Mysql? I want to try and avoid to do it programatically via my application (PHP). 
Example before deletion:

```
ID   priority    bar
1    1           66
43   2           66
54   3           66
4    4           66
```

Table after deletion

```
ID   priority    bar
1    1           66
54   3           66
4    4           66
```

would have to be updated to

```
ID   priority    bar
1    1           66
54   2           66
4    3           66
```

Many thanks for your ideas!

Edit: Due to popular demand:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo`
(`id` INT NOT NULL, `priority` INT NOT NULL , `bar` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 1, 66), (43, 2, 66), (54, 3, 66), (4, 4, 66);
```

Comment: Why do you need to reorder the sequence. It does not matter to SORT if there are missing numbers in the sequence, it will still sort appropriately

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, that is understood, however, the priority column is displayed to the user and should make sense, i.e. be sequential at all times. It is not just a technical attribute.

Comment: A smoking jacket and ebony cigarette holder. For something less elegant but more practical, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: So every time a row is deleted every row in the entire table with a higher priority needs to be updated?

Comment: Not the entire table, I have an additional column to filter on. So in the example above WHERE bar = 66. Normally you would have between 10-20 entries per unit of "bar", but I could imagine up to 100. The question for me is really, if there is some way this can be done directly on the DB or is it required to fetch the data, loop through and update the table back? The data can be selected in the correct order easily, it is just how to I create a sequence from 1,..., n and update priority for each entry directly on the DB?

Comment: What version of MySQL, please?

Comment: In the example above, because you deleted the row with priority = 2, do you mean something like: update mytable set priority = priority -1 where priority > 2 and bar = 66

Comment: Are you really you need this in the table? You can get the values sorted by `priority` from the database and generate the sequence when they are displayed to the user. You probably run a loop to show them, the loop index (plus 1 if it starts from 0) is the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what [@HoneyBoyWilson suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473878/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-create-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql/62476938#comment110491356_62473878) and write a trigger which will decrement priority on delete...

```
update foo
  set priority = priority - 1
  where priority > :whatever priority got deleted:
```

And increment on insert...

```
update foo
  set priority = priority + 1
  where priority < :whatever priority got deleted:
```

And another trigger for update.

---

But it's probably easier to leave `priority` as is and use [`rank()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) to fill in the blanks.

```
select *, rank() over w
from foo
window w as (order by priority asc)

id  priority    bar  rank() over w
1   1           66   1
54  3           66   2
4   4           66   3
```

And, if at all possible, eliminate `priority` entirely and calculate it using `rank` based on other data.